# Save multiselect c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use cshtml for my select:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Ligne">Ligne</label>
    <div class="container">
        <select name="Ligne" id="ligne" class="selectpicker" title="Select something" data-live-search="true"  multiple="multiple">
            @foreach (var item in Model.allLignes)
            {
                <option value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodeLigne)>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodeLigne)</option>

            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I send form, it saves only one value...

Can you help me?

my controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,name,begin,end,Ligne")] RT TypeRT)

 cmdPerso.CommandText = "insert into RT (name, begin, end, Ligne, CreateBy) VALUES ('" + TypeRT.name+ "','" + TypeRT.begin+ "','" + TypeRT.end+ "','" + TypeRT.Ligne+ "','" + User.Identity.Name + "')";
```

I want to use this select expression for edit form.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think you have to set the "Ligne" as array

Comment: Me too but when i create jquery alert, i have first ligne, second ligne,..., x igne .  but I tried doing so by using string list but this ididn't work..

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc 5?

Comment: I faced the same issue in my project and the solution was to make the argument as List<Ligne>, this must work with you.

Comment: Guess what happens if a line contains `'); Drop table RT;--`. Are you *sure* this isn't what happened here? *Don't* use string concatenation to create queries. Use parameterized queries, EF or a microORM like Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

Work with the tools that the ASP MVC framework provides:

- In your ViewModel, the property to which the selected values are bound must be an **array**. Available options can be stored in the `MultiSelectList` class.

  ```
  using System.Web.Mvc;

  public class MultiSelectViewModel {

      /// <summary>
      /// Selected values of the multi select.
      /// </summary>
      public string[] SelectedValues { get; set; }

      /// <summary>
      /// Possible options.
      /// </summary>
      public MultiSelectList AvailableOptions { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- In your Controller (GET case), assign the available options:

`MultiSelectList` can be instantiated by passing a collection of options and the names of the properties that hold the Value and Text of an option (e.g. "CodeLigne").

```
Ligne[] allLignes = DbContext.Lignes.ToArray(); // all possible options
// for edit use case: the options that have been selected during create use case
string[] previouslySelectedLigneCodes = new { "1", "3" }; 

// your ViewModel containing the multiselect properties
var vm = new MultiSelectViewModel(); 
vm.AvailableOptions = new MultiSelectList(
    allLignes, "CodeLigne", "NomLigne", previouslySelectedLigneCodes);
```

- In your View, you can render the MultiSelect using `ListBoxFor`:

  ```
  @model MultiSelectViewModel 

  <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedValues)">Ligne</label>
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, Model.AvailableOptions, 
                        new {@class = "selectpicker", title ="Select something"})
  ```

Further reading: [Step-By-Step Implementation of MultiSelectList In .NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1063846/Step-By-Step-Implementation-of-MultiSelectList-In).

Comment: i don't understand ...
how i can instantiate this.
Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Please see my edit on how to instantiate the ViewModel!

Comment: How I get back the data? And for Create i replace Model.AvailableOptions by null but it didn't work

Comment: Data is posted back in MultiSelectViewModel.SelectedValues. You still need  some options the user can select in the create usecase. Passing `previouslySelectedLigneCodes` in the edit usecase will select the options that were selected during create. The link i posted contains a complete example that covers all aspects.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the type of your `TypeRT.Ligne` to `List<string>` (you can change `string` to another type if needed, like `List<int>`).

Now your controller will get the list of selected values, but then your query must save them. Ideally, this list should be saved in another table and you should save each value in a separate row. That's a good normalized design.

However, it seems from your code that you save the list in a single field of the same table, perhaps comma-separated? That's not a good design and it needs to be normalized like I mentioned above, but if you really want to do so then you have to join the array items using the separator that you want:

```
String.Join(",", TypeRT.Ligne);
```

If you're using .NET < 4, you have to use `ToArray` first:

```
String.Join(",", TypeRT.Ligne.ToArray());
```

Note: your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a parameterized query instead.